# Use of "chez" with a family name?

Tags: grammaire

I have seen this written two ways:

I am going to the Hendersons'.

Je vais chez Henderson.

Je vais chez les Henderson.

I'm pretty sure but I wanted to clarify. The first one means "I'm going to Henderson's house," while the second one means "I'm going to the Hendersons' house." Am I correct?

Comment: I think no one will give a better answer than yours ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I just picked up editing privileges. I feel like I should commemorate the occasion by learning to make the accents. Is there a formatting trick, or do you all just know the alt codes? Also, how do you make the pretty yellow highlighting for examples?

Comment: Have a look on [meta] to type accentuated characters. As for quotes (yellow highlighting) just put a `>` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Aerovistae we all have proper keyboards ;) you can try http://french.typeit.org too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, Aerovistae. You have the correct answer.

*Je vais chez Henderson.* = you're visiting someone whom you call Henderson
*Je vais chez les Henderson.* = you're visiting the Hendersons (i.e. the Henderson family)

Answer (score 1):

In general case you are right

- **Chez Henderson** means *in Henderson's house*
- **Chez les Hendersons** means *at the Hendersons*

But *chez Henderson* could also mean *in the Henderson family*, mainly for old people. For example

> *Comment ils vont chez Henderson ?*

means

> How are the Hendersons?

Answer (score 0):

Short way to distinguish these :

**« Je vais chez les Henderson. »** would mean that you'll visit the Henderson family at their home.

**« Je vais chez Henderson. »** would mean that you're going to a shop or a store named like that.

Comment: *Je vais chez Henderson* peut très bien signifier qu'on va chez quelqu'un sans pour autant aller voir sa famille…

Comment: Bizarrement, je n'utiliserais pas *chez* pour un magasin, mais plutôt *à/au*. J'utiliserais *chez* pour désigner la chaine de magasins en général et *à/au* pour un magasin particulier.

Comment: @Bruno, ça peut être une question intéressante: on va bien chez Michou ou chez le coiffeur, mais à la pharmacie ou au supermarché. Va-t-on chez Leclerc, à Leclerc ou encore au Leclerc?